# Which of these is true?

Tags: functions, continuity

Suppose $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is a continuous nondecreasing function with $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Define $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ by $g(y)=\min\{x\in[0,1]\mid f(x)\ge y\}$.

Then:

(A) $g$ is nondecreasing

(B) If $g$ is continuous then $f$ is strictly increasing.

I was able to figure out that (A) is true, however I am unable to prove that (B) is false. It seems to me that if $f$ is not constant over any interval, then $g$ should be continuous and vice-versa.

Comment: I don't understand (B): it is **given** that $\;f\;$ is non-decreasing, thus what is there to prove?!

Comment: My apologies! (B) should be read "Strictly increasing" instead of "nondecreasing".

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a function f which gives a contradiction to (B). We use $f: [0,1] \to [0,1] $ with

$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2x,  & \text{if $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2}$ } \\
1, & \text{if $\frac{1}{2} \le x \le 1$ } 
\end{cases}$

f is not strictly increasing but still nondecreasing. In contrast to this g is still continuous, as all the minimas are taking place in $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$

Comment: 1.5 - x is not nondecreasing, which is a given property of f

Comment: Ah I see, I guess that takes away the answer

Comment: so I edited the function, it should work now, atleast to me